# Como insertar números decimales en celdas de ventana tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ventana, celdas, insertar

Quiero insertar números decimales de 0.01 hasta finalizar con el entero de 1.0 en diez celdas diferentes, en donde el primer grupo de números decimales comenzará de 0.01 a 0.10 en la primera celda y continuará de 0.11 a 0.20 en la siguiente celda, culminando el último grupo de 0.90 al 1.0 en la última celda diez.

```
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

for r in range(0, 10):
    for c in range(0, 10):
        bonus = [x/100 for x in range(1,101)]
        cell = Entry(root, width=20)
        cell.grid(row=r, column=c)
        cell.insert(bonus, '({}, {})'.format(r, c))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

En total son 10 celdas, así que debes usar un for que imprima 10 números con 10 celdas.

Vamos con un ejemplo más simple, imprimir los números del 0 al 10 en grupos de 2.

No puedes usar un range completo del 0 al 10 ya que estarías imprimiendo todos juntos.

El primero rango va de 0 a 2, el segundo de 2 a 4, el tercero de 4 a 6 y así sucesivamente. En código:

```
range(0, 2)
range(2, 4)
range(4, 6)
```

Si prestas atención, la fórmula para el inicio de cada rango es `n * 2` y el final es el mismo número más 2 (la cantidad de números que se imprimen por vez).

Nuevamente, en código:

```
range(n * 2, n * 2 + 2)
```

Bueno, si imprimes los números del 0 al 100 en grupos de diez, vas a imprimir un total de (100 - 0) / 10 = 10 grupos.

En código:

```
for n in range(10):
    print([x for x in range(n * 10, n * 10 + 10)])
```

O adaptado para que produzca decimales:

```
for n in range(10):
    print([x/100 for x in range(n * 10, n * 10 + 10)])
```

Comment: Logro conseguir las 10 celdas  con el range(0,10) de hecho, sustituyendo la pieza de código :  cell.insert(bonus, '({}, {})'.format(r, c))  e incluyendo: cell.insert(0, str(bonus[r*10+c])) se insertan los grupos de números decimales de manera ascendente en la celdas correspondiente pero en orden horizontal y estoy tratando de que el orden ascendente sea en orden vertical...